# Upgrade an element to a custom element

Tags: javascript, custom-element

I'm trying to upgrade a normal element to a custom element. This example does not work so maybe this is not possible?

```js
customElements.define('html-h1-heading-element', class extends HTMLHeadingElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    console.log('Hello from custom element');
  }
}, {
  extends: 'h1'
});

const el = document.querySelector('h1');
el.setAttribute('is', 'html-h1-heading-element');
console.log(el);
```

```html
<h1>Hello, world</h1>
```

Comment: OK, what are you trying to do? Dynamically change an existing element on the page to a custom element? Right now you've presented [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) because the `is` is hardly the only thing that determines what kind of an element is it. And the type of objects in JS is not determined by their properties - if you have an object and add properties to it that make it match a `class Foo`, the object will not dynamically be changed to be an instance of `Foo`.

Comment: @VLAZ I have a custom elements that extends the `h1`.  Adding the `is` attribute is how you normally do this. Instead of adding this manually in the code I would like to add this using javascript. Do you have a clearer picture of what I'm trying to do?

Comment: What you could do is get the content of the `h1`, create your custom `html-h1-heading-element` with this content. And then replace the `h1` with your new element.

Comment: And then use [replaceWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceWith)  (not supported in IE11)

Comment: I think we can't upgrade a normal element to a custom element using script. But it does work if we set hardcoded `<h1 is="html-h1-heading-element">Hello, world</h1>` in html. check : https://mdn.github.io/web-components-examples/word-count-web-component/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 types of Elements:

- Standard Elements
- Autonomous Custom Elements AE (extend from HTMLElement)
- Customized Built-In Elements CBIE (extend from Standard Elements)
  The `is` attribute is not your regular Element Attribute.
  **You can't change/setAttribute("is",...) a Element to something else after definition.**
  The `is` attribute is used when the element is created by the DOM parser, not on DOM mutations.

Customized Elements are **not supported in Safari**, and Apple has stated they never will be.

source: https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/509
[image]

You can try a [Polyfill](https://github.com/WebReflection/built-in-element),
or just not use them, and stick to Autonomous Elements (extend HTMLElement).

Note that all Baseclasses out there, Lit, Hybrids, Stencil etc, all extend from HTMLElement,
they don't do Customized Built-In Elements

If you continue with Customized Elements (not working on Safari) note that:

```
document.body.append(
  document.createElement("IMG", { is: "white-queen" })
);
```

properly creates a *Customized Built-In* DOM element,
but it **does not set** the `is` attribute on the DOM element.
So if you need it as CSS selector you have to explicitly set it yourself.

```
document.body.appendChild(
  document.createElement("IMG", { is: "white-queen" })
).setAttribute("is", "white-queen");
```

This then allows the CSS selector `[is=*"white"]` to select all white pieces.  Which is not possible with ***partial*** tag names.

All my experiments in: https://chessmeister.github.io/

I have never used Customized Built-In Elements since.